# Fixing a UTF8 encoded database that was dumped using an incorrect encoding?

Tags: mysql, encoding

The question is probably a little vague so let me elucidate:

- System OS is Ubuntu Linux 14.10 LTS
- The Servers default encoding is Latin1
- The database default encoding is/was UTF8
- The data was dumped by piping `mysqldump > out.sql`

On re-importation back into the same engine into a database created with:

```
CREATE DATABASE test DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

it was re-imported using a simple `Source out.sql;`

As a result a number of :

> Warning (Code 1300): Invalid utf8 character string: '9CD4BB'

... warnings during importation.

I have tried using `-verbose` on the MySQL client, but it produces a large quantity of unnecessary information (`out.sql` is around 845MB)

Settings:

```
| character_set_client                              | utf8
| character_set_connection                          | utf8  
| character_set_database                            | latin1
| character_set_filesystem                          | binary
| character_set_results                             | utf8  
| character_set_server                              | latin1
| character_set_system                              | utf8  
| character_sets_dir                                | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
| collation_connection                              | utf8_general_ci
| collation_database                                | latin1_swedish_ci     
| collation_server                                  | latin1_swedish_ci
```

1. Is it possible to generate  a smaller file containing the SQL statements that generated the warnings?
2. My assumption here is that during the data dump the data was converted to latin1 and saved as `out.sql`.  There are characters in latin1 that cannot be represented under utf8.  It is possible to convert them back, or at least a `grep` that can show me a small amount of the offending text - remembering that I think grep returns the entire line (and sql exports have no hard coded line endings)?
3. Given that I have lost the original data - any ideas on overall recovery strategy?

Comment: The only theory I have is that it's trying to represent a binary data blob as utf

Comment: Also I was concerned that I caused the issue by piping mysqldump output

Comment: I have confirmed it was indeed the method of backup that corrupted the data.
I reviewed a backup from 2 weeks ago and it has non of the problems importing.

It was also backed up by mysqlbackup but on windows based machine.

Comment: So given I now have a healthy database from 2 weeks ago, but a functional but corrupted database from yesterday I want to remove the corrupt records from the recent data using the backup from 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot turns out the issue here is that BINARY data fields can not (almost ever) be UTF8 encoded.  hence when you dump using mysqldump (which doesnt change the data or encode it) it will dump fine HOWEVER when you use source <data.sql> it will read the file with the encoding in this case UTF8 - it doesnt change the data - but reports if it finds data that doesnt match the encoding hence the warning.